# How do I enable vertical gridlines in Excel 2013 Pivot Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

By default, when creating a stacked area Pivot Chart, Excel 2013 does not include vertical gridlines. How can I enable them?

Comment: This used to be straightforward, but they made it much less obvious in 2013. It took me a long time to figure it out and initial google searches were fruitless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, click the chart area. That will reveal the `Chart Elements` plus sign icon and the `Chart Styles` paintbrush icon. Click the `Chart Elements` icon. This should reveal a list of checkboxes for things like `Axes`, `Axis Titles`, etc. Ensure that the `Gridlines` checkbox is checked. Then, click on the right arrow icon next to `Gridlines` to reveal another list of checkboxes for things like `Primary Major Horizontal`, `Primary Major Vertical`, etc. Ensure that the appropriate vertical selections are checked.

This image should help:

[image: Chart Elements checkbox list with Gridlines sub-list revealed]

See also:

https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/31/chart-elements-customizing-your-chart/